# Is there a way to send transaction in anchor, besides using solana-sdk

Tags: anchor, transactions

I am trying to sign and send a transaction from anchor.

Is there a way to do so without using `solana-sdk`

Answer (score 1):

You can interact directly the RPC api.

https://docs.solana.com/api/http#sendtransaction